# turn tuple of dicts into single dict

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have data:

```
({'name': 'bob', 'sex': 'male'}, {'name': 'sally', 'sex': 'female'})
```

I want to have

```
{'bob': 'male', 'sally': 'female'}
```

Whats a fast, easy way to do it?  The data is always n-length tuple of dicts with the same key/value pair.

Comment: not sure what the downvote was for.  bad formatting maybe. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a dict comprehension:

```
{d['name']: d['sex'] for d in input_structure}
```

This produces *one* dictionary where the keys and values are taken from the two keys in the input dictionaries.

If you are using Python 2.6 or older, you'll have to resort to a `dict()` call with generator expression instead:

```
dict((d['name'], d['sex']) for d in input_structure)
```

Demo:

```
>>> sample = ({'name': 'bob', 'sex': 'male'}, {'name': 'sally', 'sex': 'female'})
>>> {d['name']: d['sex'] for d in sample}
{'bob': 'male', 'sally': 'female'}
>>> dict((d['name'], d['sex']) for d in sample)
{'bob': 'male', 'sally': 'female'}
```

Comment: that was fast, awesome that I cant accept this for 8 whole minutes!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ({'name': 'bob', 'sex': 'male'}, {'name': 'sally', 'sex': 'female'})

print {y['name']:y['sex'] for y in x} 

>> {'bob': 'male', 'sally': 'female'}
```